# CNN keras hand written recognition has high accuracy but poor predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am basically doing this for a school project and followed some guides to make a neuron network using CNN. Libraries I am using are cv2, NumPy, TensorFlow, and matplotlib. The problem currently I am facing is that my network has high accuracy but very bad predictions. I made sure the pictures are inverted and 28x28. I also expand the number of images to predict from 5 to 10. I also tried adding more layers but didn't help either. If anyone can help me out would be awesome! I am also very new to this so please explain the best you can!

Example of the output:[As you can see, the hand-writing isn't bad or anything but it still can't predict that it's a 6 but a 1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyXgI.png)

[Here is the Epoch with an accuracy of 99% basically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9QKQ.png)

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf


mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(a_train, b_train), (a_test, b_test) = mnist.load_data()

 a_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(a_train, axis=1)
 a_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(a_test, axis=1)
 model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
 model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)))
 model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=255, activation=tf.nn.relu))
 model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=255, activation=tf.nn.relu))
 model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=20, activation=tf.nn.softmax))



 model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

 model.fit(a_train, b_train, epochs=50)

 lost, accuracy = model.evaluate(a_train, b_train)
 print(lost)
 print(accuracy)

 model.save('test.model')

for x in range(1,11):
 img = cv2.imread(fr'C:\Users\Eric\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\test.model\{x}.png')[:,:,0]
 img = np.invert(np.array([img]))
 prediction = model.predict(img)
 print(f'My Guess is: {np.argmax(prediction)}')
 plt.imshow(img[0], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
 plt.show()
```

**Somethings I tried doing:**
I tried adding more layers assuming that it will train and have a better prediction.
I added more samples numbers to see if I can have a higher prediction. I went from 5 to 10 but still a 20% right prediction.
I have tried changing about of Epoch and tried more batch size but also didn't work.

I am pretty much stuck at this point trying my best to understand it but not able to improve it at all. If anyone has any tips, please let me know!

Comment: Make sure to normalize your images when predicting. Also your current code isn't a CNN as it does not use any convolution layers

Comment: Without CNNs, you are just matching raw pixels and the mnist is well-centered. Also your last layer should include 10 units instead of 20?

Answer (score 0):

You need to normalize your images when predicting. `cv2.imread` creates an array from 0 to 255. You can normalize it by dividing `img` by `255.`

Your image you use to predict should also have white text on a black background.

Lastly, you do not need the `np.invert`.

So your code should be

```
for x in range(1, 11):
     img = np.expand_dims(cv2.imread(f'C:\Users\Eric\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\test.model\{x}.png')[:, :, 0], 0) / 255.
     prediction = model.predict(img)
     print(f'My Guess is: {np.argmax(prediction)}')
     plt.imshow(img[0], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
     plt.show()
```

Comment: So I did what you told me. I have changed the sample numbers to a black background with white text. It still only has a 50% prediction out of the 10 sample pictures I gave. It has a really bad time recognizing numbers like 7,6,9. Is there a way to fix this? Is it possible to let the network train more? I still have a 97% accuracy but with a 50% prediction correct.

Comment: One possibility is that your model is overfitting. Try reducing the number of epochs from 50 to maybe 5 or 10.
You can also try adding convolution layers before flattening it. This will make the network more resilient to images that are slightly off-centered